# Intermediate value, $|x-y|=2/5, f(x)=f(y)$

Tags: real-analysis

> Let $f: [0,1] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be continuous with $f(1)=f(0)$. If $h\in  (0, 1/2)$ is not of the form $1/n$, there does not necessarily exist
> $|x − y| = h$ satisfying $f(x) = f(y)$. Provide an example that illustrates
> this using h = 2/5.

I'm really mind blown with this question. I could share with you what I've done but its just some squiggles of a graph and it feels like there is absolutely no way I can prevent a gap of $2/5$ sneaking in. I'm taking $|x-y|=2/5$ to be, "Can I fit a ruler under my curve of length 2/5 so that it touches both sides" and I just cannot see a situation where that doesn't happen. I'm guessing that my intuition has been flawed by my drawing attempt and in fact the solution is a very non-differentiable curve.

The same question has been "answered" here [Using Intermediate Value Theorem for continuous functions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2508153/using-intermediate-value-theorem-for-continuous-functions) but unfortunately this poor fellow has been entirely mislead by a false example.

Comment: This is the subject of the Universal Chord theorem.  In [the accepted answer to this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/612462/intuition-for-the-universal-chord-theorem) there is a sketch of how to achieve this.

Comment: I don't think the question as clearly stated as it might be. As I understand it, you are required to provide an example of a continuous function $f(x)$ with $f(1) = f(0) $ and $f(x_1) = f(x_2) \implies |x_1 - x_2| \ne 2/5$

Comment: @Tom: The question asks you to think of a function $f$ where $f$ is continuos, $f(0) = f(1)$, and forall $x$ in domain, $f(x + 0.4) \neq f(x)$.

Comment: @Kaind I think that is just the negation of what I wrote (i.e. the same thing) ?

Comment: @Kaind As I understand the query, $(x + 0.4)$ must also be in the domain, which means that $0 \leq x \leq 0.6$.

Comment: @Tom: that's correct. 
user2661923: Yes I know, i was feeling a bit lazy to write $[0,0.6]$, hence I just wrote 'domain' which isn't entirely correct.

Comment: Here are examples as well: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/16374/42969

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just had a huge chat with user @user21820 on this problem. Do see his answer at:
[Intuition for the Universal Chord Theorem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/612462/intuition-for-the-universal-chord-theorem)

Either way I'll just write an explicit function as an answer for this problem:
$f(x) =
\begin{cases}
-10x &, x \in [0,0.2) \\
1 + 15(x-0.4) &, x \in [0.2,0.4) \\
1 -10(x - 0.4) &, x \in [0.4,0.6) \\
2 + 15(x-0.8) &, x \in [0.6,0.8) \\
-10(x - 1) &, x \in [0.8,1] \\
\end{cases}
 $

The above function $f(x)$ is just a bunch of alternatively parallel line segments joined at the endpoints. It satisfies the property:
$$x \in [0,0.6] \Rightarrow f(x + 0.4) = f(x) + 1$$
A plot for f(x) is given by:
[image]

Comment: I gave +1, but this is pretty much the same plot I put in my answer! Observation that $f(x+0.4)=f(x)+1$ is nice.

Comment: Hey, I realize you have the 'cylinder ' approach to plotting the curve. But user21820's answer to that problem on the link in my answer describes a slightly different method of construction which allows us to find $f$ s.t. $f(x+0.4) = f(x) + c$ for any constant $c$.

Answer (score 2):

I made a picture following the sketch of **Brian Rushton** at the post linked by **Ross Millikan**. More generally, if you want to avoid having $f(x)=f(x+a)$ where $0<a<1$ is not of the form $\frac{1}{n}$, the idea would be to take the quotient of the $x$-axis by $a \mathbb{Z}$ and draw the graph on the resulting cylinder.

[image]